# Shotwell: Storing part of library on external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, shotwell, photo-management, photo

I am trying to sort out my Ubuntu photo workflow, and I wondered if anyone could offer some advice.

I store my photo library on an external HDD, which is on my desk at home. I would like to be able to import and process my photos on my local HDD, and then move them over to the external HDD when I get home. I would also like to be able to access a small thumbnail when not connected to the external HDD.

This seems like a problem which must be fairly common, but I've got no idea how to deal with it. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a real problem, also for me. Once your disk is full, you need a solution...

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/547839/shotwell-how-to-browse-external-library-without-external-drive-plugged-in/1005846#1005846

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [gThumb](https://live.gnome.org/gthumb). It is quite simple but yet very powerful underneath. It facilitates file system folder structure and has more on top of it (tags, catalogs, marks, batch processes, simple image editing, export/import). So it won't be a problem to manage PC photos and external HDD photos from one program and move them one way around.

As to having a set of small thumbnails I guess you gonna have to do some scripting, which is also possible in [gThumb](https://live.gnome.org/gthumb). I've never herd of anything like this.